# Откуда у последовательного интерфейса столько каналов передач?

Tags: железо

Разбираюсь с шиной PCI Express. Есть разные ее виды при разных версиях - x1, x4, x8, x16, x32. Пропускная способность растет в геометрической прогрессии, как и количество каналов передач под каждый вид. Почему такое количество линий, если PCIe использует передачу бит за битом?